# React webpack production build not booting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I have created a single page React app using `React`, `webpack` & `react-router`. The app is working fine locally without any errors or warnings.

The problem is that once I create a production build and try to run the `index.html` file inside `dist` folder it is not booting my react app.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.15.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-youtube": "^7.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js")],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    //historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.html")
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
}
```

`npm run build` is creating a `dist` folder with `index_bundle`, `main.css`, `index.html` but on opening index.html the production build is not working. Am I missing something? 
Any help will be appreciated.

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="main-wrapper"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

`index_bundle.js` size is quite large hence sharing the pastebin url

https://pastebin.com/i7VcfFgLd

Comment: `the production build is not working` <- I cannot guess what it is doing.  Can you provide errors/stack traces/more information that might indicate what is wrong other than `will not boot`

Comment: Getting no console errors in the browser.

Comment: @mikeb added Pastebin URL  as in Jsbin and others it was exceeding size limit

Comment: How are you trying to run "index.html"? Through a web server or using "file://" protocol? Because the latter won't work while using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom.

Comment: Thanks, @Edward just figured out the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is looking for the answer, `<BrowserRouter>` doesn't work with static routes, I replaced it with `<Hashrouter>` and it worked.